# Fluent Nhibernate One to One mapping with non primary key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, one-to-one

Not able to figure out the proper mapping for below table.

```
  Table: ItemSale    {ItemCode, SaleDate, Qty, SaleCode}  
         ItemCode and SaleDate are composite key.
         SaleCode is a derived column, generated from the combination of ItemCode and SaleDate column. 

  Table: ItemSaleDetail {SaleCode, Agent}
         SaleCode is a primary key and foreign key from ItemSale table for SaleCode column.
```

**Entities and their mappings are given below.**

ItemSale

```
public class ItemSale
{
    public virtual string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Date { get; set; }
    public virtual string  SaleCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemSaleDetail SaleDetail { get; set; }
}

public class ItemSaleMap : ClassMap<ItemSale>
{
    public ItemSaleMap()
    {
        Table("ItemSale");
        CompositeId()
          .KeyReference(x => x.ItemCode, "ItemCode")
          .KeyProperty(x => x.Date, "SaleDate");
        HasOne(x => x.SaleDetail).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

ItemSaleDetail

```
public class ItemSaleDetail
{
    public virtual string ItemSaleCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Agent { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemSale SaleParent { get; set; }

}

public class ItemSaleDetailMap : ClassMap<ItemSaleDetail>
{
    public ItemSaleDetailMap()
    {
        Table("ItemSaleDetail");
        Id(x => x.ItemSaleCode).GeneratedBy.Foreign("SaleParent");
        Map(x => x.Agent, "Agent");
        HasOne(x => x.SaleParent).Constrained(); 
    }
}
```

I have given above the basic one to one mapping being used in traditional way which I know is wrong in this case.
Please suggest how to provide the proper mapping in this case.
Also if derived column SaleCode to be generated by the application, how can we have this property in my entity. As it is not allowed have multiple mapping for a single column.

Comment: Your tables and entities are really complicated. If your domain model is complicated you should start to re-think it. My suggestion would be: do your best to have entities with [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) IDs *(generated, **WITHOUT** any business value)*. E.g. `Long`, `int`... All your mapping will then become easier and you will gain more from tools like NHibernate. If you think that your current stuff is the best, I would at least suggest to use `SaleCode` column as a key (string). That will solve your issue with One-To-One...But, do think about surrogate keys

Comment: Thanks Radim for your quick suggestion. Could you please suggest again how to do mapping if i change the ItemSaleCode to GeneratedBy.Assigned from GeneratedBy.Foreign("SaleParent").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, with assignable ID we can do it like this. Firstly we should be sure, that the ID is assigned, so we can adjust the getter of the `<id>` **`ItemSaleCode`** like this:

```
public class ItemSaleDetail
{
    string _itemSaleCode;

    public virtual string ItemSaleCode
    {
        get { return _itemSaleCode ?? SaleParent.SaleCode ; }
        set { _itemSaleCode  = value; }
    }
```

Now, we need mapping like this:

```
<id name="ItemSaleCode" column="SaleCode" type="String" generator="assigned" />
<one-to-one name="SaleParent" class="ItemSale"
    constrained="true" property-ref="SaleCode" />
...
```

...

Which in Fluent should be like this:

```
public ItemSaleDetailMap()
{
    ...
    Id(x => x.ItemSaleCode)
        .CustomType<String>()
        .Column("SaleCode")
        .GeneratedBy.Assigned();

    HasOne(x => x.SaleParent)
       .ProeprtyRef("SaleCode")
       .Constrained(); 
}


public ItemSaleMap()
{
    References(x => x.SaleDetail)
       .Column("SaleCode")
       .Unique()
       .Cascade.All();
    Map(x => x.SaleCode)
       .Column("SaleCode")
       .Not.Update()
       .Not.Insert()
}
```

But again, Surrogate INT or LONG keys are the way I would go for sure...

Comment: Great to see that sir ;) Mighty NHibernate ;)

Comment: Is this possible if ItemSaleDetail instead has a primary surrogate key but ItemSale uses SaleCode?